# AG Charts: Access current min/max graph values as modified by navigator

Tags: angular, ag-charts

Enabling navigator allows Users to redefine the min/max values presented by chart (eg. a bar chart).
The question is **if and how it is possible to access the currently visualized chart min/max values** as long as the navigator handlers are moved

Looked everywhere in docs and examples but found anything